# Is SOAP 1.1 envelope without namespace prefixes valid one?

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, web, xml-namespaces

Is SOAP 1.1 envelope without namespace prefixes valid one ?

I have developed ASMX web service in .Net . Outbound clients that call me and send messages in format like this :

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://myCustomNamespace.com/">                  
  <soapenv:Header/>                                                     
  <soapenv:Body>                                                        
    <web:Test/>  
  </soapenv:Body>  
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

are processed properly. The problem begun when client that runs under IBM's Cast Iron sent envelope in following format :

```html
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">            
   <Body>                                                               
      <Test xmlns="http://myCustomNamespace.com/" />  
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Related with http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/   in paragraph *3. Relation to XML* :

> A SOAP application SHOULD include the proper SOAP namespace on all elements and attributes defined by SOAP in messages that it generates. A SOAP application MUST be able to process SOAP namespaces in messages that it receives. It MUST discard messages that have incorrect namespaces (see section 4.4) and it MAY process SOAP messages without SOAP namespaces as though they had the correct SOAP namespaces.

Related with all is it expected from my side to process both requests ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample message is fully namespace-qualified - it's just that it uses empty prefixes (a feature that is mis-named 'default namespaces' in the standards).

You can easily verify the fact that every node is namespace-qualified by reading the XML into a DOMDocument and looking at the `.nameSpace` properties of the nodes.

Where things get tricky is the child nodes of body entries, if the corresponding WSDL specifies that the element form is 'unqualified' or if the standard encoding rules apply ("Accessors whose names are local to their containing types have unqualified element names; all others have qualified names.").

In that case the use of empty prefixes ('default namespaces') requires that body entry children be explicitly qualified as having no namespace:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">            
   <Body>                                                               
      <foo xmlns="some-URI">
         <result xmlns="">meow</result>
      </foo>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Otherwise they would inherit the namespace of the nearest enclosing default namespace and thus fail validation.

SOAP envelopes that are not namespace-qualified are a different kettle of fish. [SOAP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/) says:

*A SOAP application SHOULD include the proper SOAP namespace on all elements and attributes defined by SOAP in messages that it generates. A SOAP application MUST be able to process SOAP namespaces in messages that it receives. It MUST discard messages that have incorrect namespaces (see section 4.4) and **it MAY process SOAP messages without SOAP namespaces as though they had the correct SOAP namespaces.***

In other words: you MUST process

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">            
   <Body>                                                               
      <foo xmlns="some-URI"/>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

and you MAY process

```
<Envelope>
   <Body>                                                               
      <foo xmlns="some-URI"/>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```